# CoreData and Swift's Actor and Sendable

Tags: ios, swift, core-data, actor, sendable

I am trying to understand Swift's Actors, but failed. I am playing around with the following example.
I want to setup a `LocalStore` that uses an `NSPersistentContainer`.
The `struct LocalStore` should be used by a `StoreManager` declared as

```
actor StoreManager {
  private let localStore = LocalStore()
  init() {
    localStore.test()
  }
}
```

`LocalStore` is declared as

```
import CoreData
import Foundation

struct LocalStore: Sendable {
  private let localPersistentContainer = NSPersistentContainer()

  func test() {
    print("test")
  }
}
```

Here I get 2 compiler errors, shown here as comments:

- `import CoreData // Add '@_predatesConcurrency' to suppress 'Sendable'-related warnings from module 'CoreData'`
- `private let localPersistentContainer = NSPersistentContainer() // Stored property 'localPersistentContainer' of 'Sendable'-conforming struct 'LocalStore' has non-sendable type 'NSPersistentContainer'`

I neither know if it is save or advisable to suppress 'Sendable'-related warnings from module 'CoreData', nor what to do with the non-sendable type 'NSPersistentContainer'.
Any help is welcome.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By now I understand the situation a little better.
`LocalStore` is declared as `Sendable`, i.e. it should be possible to be passed around thread-safe. Now assume its property `localPersistentContainer` had been declared as follows:

```
let localPersistentContainer = NSPersistentContainer()
```

`NSPersistentContainer` has some properties that can be set, like `persistentStoreDescriptions`. It is thus possible that such a property can be changed within `LocalStore`, as well as by anything that has been passed `LocalStore` to, i.e. this would not be thread-safe. In this case the warning

```
Stored property 'localPersistentContainer' of 'Sendable'-conforming struct 'LocalStore' has non-sendable type 'NSPersistentContainer'
```

**is** justified.
However, in my case `localPersistentContainer` has been declared as follows:

```
private let localPersistentContainer = NSPersistentContainer()
```

This means that anything that receives a `LocalStore` cannot access the private property `localPersistentContainer`, and thus the compiler warning is **not** justified, since the compiler is of course aware of that.

As the other compiler warning suggested,

```
@_predatesConcurrency import CoreData
```

suppresses all `Sendable` warnings created by the CoreData module. While this works, it is to my mind dangerous because it suppresses also justified warnings.